# C++ export mangled names

Tags: c++, dll, name-mangling

I have written some template functions, and I would like to export every single (explicitly instantiated) version of them.

`Python_wrapper.cpp` will be a DLL.

***Templates.h***

```
namespace PEParserNamespace {
    template<typename T, class PEParserBaseImpl>
    inline PEParserBaseImpl& openFile(T lpFileName, PEParserBaseImpl* pPEParserBaseImpl) noexcept {
        return *pPEParserBaseImpl;
    }
}
```

***Python_wrapper.cpp***

```
//explicit instantiation
namespace PEParserNamespace {
    template PEParser & _cdecl openFile<const wchar_t*, PEParser>(const wchar_t*, PEParser*) noexcept;
    template PEParser & _cdecl openFile<const char*, PEParser>(const char*, PEParser*) noexcept;
}
```

The problem is, when using `__declspec(dllexport)` I will get mangled names.

There are several methods for exporting a definition:

1. `__declspec(dllexport)` to use in source code
2. An `EXPORTS` statement in a `.def` file
3. A comment directive in the source code, `#pragma comment(linker, "/export: definition ")`.

`extern "C"` would result in a linker error because of the overloaded function (`openFile`).

The second approach (using an `EXPORTS` statement in a `.def` file) would force me to manually find out the mangled name of each function, and the mangled names can change between compiler versions (as far as I know). So this is not very satisfying.

The best approach I have found so far is to use `#pragma comment(linker, "/export: definition ")` as follows:

***Templates.h***

```
namespace PEParserNamespace {
    template<typename T, class PEParserBaseImpl>
    inline PEParserBaseImpl& openFile(T lpFileName, PEParserBaseImpl* pPEParserBaseImpl) noexcept {
#pragma comment(linker, "/EXPORT:" __FUNCTION__"someString" "=" __FUNCDNAME__  )
        return *pPEParserBaseImpl;
    }
}
```

The only problem is that this approach generates one, and only one, export but I need an export for every single overload (generated by the compiler).

My last idea is to do some linker script magic (just an idea).

Comment: You need to be able to differentiate the different overloads/templates/instantiations. That's what name mangling is for. It should stay the same unless your ABI changes. What symbol names do you expect the functions to have?

Comment: Marking the template `inline` is wrong. You are not intending to use it as an inline function (since you want to export it so somewhere that apparently doesn't have the definition).

Comment: How is the DLL intended to be used? Apparently not from C++? In that case it would be much safer to write C wrapper functions around all of the instantiations, so that you have a C interface that is much easier to work with.

Comment: @user17732522 I want something more readable, so I dont have to type in that cryptic name, when using my dll.

Comment: @user17732522 yes I could just build wrappers around every single explicite instantiation, but I was hoping to find some more elegant way.

Comment: You can write a C-style wrapper *instead of* an explicit instantiation. Such a wrapper won't be much larger than that explicit instantiation it's replacing. You could also write a macro to stamp them out.

Comment: Can you list all names you want exported?